# how to call parameterized javascript function in the WebKit?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, proj4js, mobile-webkit

I am trying to pass 2 parameters to a javascript function.This code `webview.loadUrl("javascript: function_to_call();");` works fine without parameters but i couldn't use it with parameters.

This is javascript junction :

```js
function changeLocation(_lon , _lat){
    var zoom=16;
    var lonLat = new OpenLayers.LonLat( _lon , _lat ).transform(         
        new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), 
        map.getProjectionObject());

    map.setCenter (lonLat, zoom);
}
```

And this is how i call it from java :

```java
webView.loadUrl("javascript:changeLocation( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 );") ;
```

Edit: I couldn't find the problem and i changed my approach, now i am injecting whole javascript function with desired changes everytime when i need to. It is not best solution but it works. Thank you everyone for your help.

Comment: @dirhem: Is this `loadUrl()` (note: capital U) on the `WebView` widget in Java? Or something else?

Comment: @ CommonsWare Sorry i just mistyped here and yes it is WebView widget's loadUrl function.

Comment: Could you post the source code that is giving you trouble? Also, are there any error messages?

Comment: @ Jake I have posted the source coude and no i am not having any error message.

Comment: did you try webView.loadUrl('javascript:changeLocation( "-0.1279688" ,"51.5077286" );') ;?

Comment: @josh.trow i did and not working either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you have looks fine. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/WebView/GeoWeb2/) that demonstrates an almost identical syntax.

Answer (score 6):

Try changing `webView.loadUrl("javascript:changeLocation( -0.1279688 ,51.5077286 );") ;`

to `webView.loadUrl("javascript:changeLocation( '-0.1279688' ,'51.5077286' );") ;`
and maybe getting rid of the `;`

I just had a similar problem and I fixed it by adding the `''` around my parameter.  I didn't have a semicolon in my solution either and it worked so you may need to remove it.