# How can i load my js file in the android?

Tags: javascript, android, html

Hi I am very new to java script in android? My problem is my files not loaded in the android assets.

When i run my code i got exception like.

```
07-08 11:49:10.809: I/chromium(25627): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined", source:  (1)
07-08 11:49:11.100: I/chromium(25627): [INFO:CONSOLE(78)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getContext' of null", source: file:///android_asset/keyGasGraphBuilder.js (78)
```

But In my code i have added all the files in the assets.

and also i have added my code.js file in the html page while loading

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/code.js"></script>
```

and from the code i have call like

```
duvaltriangle.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        WebSettings setting =duvaltriangle.getSettings();
        duvaltriangle.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Dynamic Ratings - Duval DEMO.htm");

        String name = "Duval 2b OLTC Type IIb";

        duvaltriangle.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction(\""+name+"\")");
```

My js file:

Please tell me where i missed. I think i have done all the procedure right way.

```
function myFunction(name) 
 {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = name;
 }
```

Comment: Since you load and then a microsecond later, call the function, it *probably* hasn't parsed.  For a discussion of this, see [this potential duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4195514/how-to-call-parameterized-javascript-function-in-the-webkit)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
duvaltriangle.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/Dynamic Ratings - Duval DEMO.htm");
        duvaltriangle.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                String name = "Duval 2b OLTC Type IIb";
                duvaltriangle.loadUrl("javascript:myFunction(\""+name+"\")");
            }
        });
```

Because it takes time to load url. So, scripts must be loaded when page finishes loading.

Comment: Where did `graphDraw` come from?

Comment: @JeremyMiller Sorry, by mistake :)

Comment: Nice.  Look good now.  Every programmer experiences the joys of copy-and-paste coding... so fast and sometimes a bit surprising. :)

Comment: @JeremyMiller hehe true story. :)

Comment: Thank you @berserk. Problem is loading time is very less. So i separated that code and take some time after loading.

Comment: @Nava2011 Was based on JeremyMiller's comment. Glad it helped :)